# How to put a view on the back button of navigation bar?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

How to put a view on the back button  of navigation bar?

Not on title view, but on the back button. It seems like to me that the back button is a UIBarButtonItem, which doesn't inherite UIView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it programmatically using [initWithCustomView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithCustomView:).

[AtomicElementViewController.m](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TheElements/Listings/Classes_AtomicElementViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007419-Classes_AtomicElementViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_10) has a good example of this.